# Upgrade to 14.04: sticky/unresponsive touchpad - requires more pressure?

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, synaptics

I recently upgraded my Toshiba Satellite C50D from 12.04 to 14.04.  Everything works great except the touchpad.  Strangely, it is working, but it is noticeably unresponsive and feels "sticky".  With some experimentation I *think* it requires greater pressure before it responds.  The thing is that if I boot back into 12.04 I do not have this problem, so it must be a software issue.  I have checked:

- All parameters given by `xinput` are identical, except the device name has changed from "PS/2 Generic Mouse" to "ALPS PS/2 Device"
- The settings in Settings > Mouse/Touchpad are the same, except for the new two-finger scrolling things.

Does anyone have any idea as to how I can set up my touchpad to be the same as in 12.04?

Comment: Perhaps the kernel driver is behaving differently. You could try updating to a later mainline kernel to see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

1.Check whether the kernel has detected the Touchpad or not by executing at a terminal:

`cat /proc/bus/input/devices`

If Touchpad is detected, then something like the following will appear: `Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"`

If Touchpad is not detected then the following will appear: `Name="ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse"`

In this case the bug must be a kernel issue.

2.Check whether xserver has detected the Touchpad correctly by executing at a terminal:

`xinput --list`

You should see the same name of Touchpad as above.

3.Check whether the synaptics module is correctly loaded in xserver or not via executing at a terminal:

`cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep -i synaptics`

4.You may also want to try investigating with:

`evtest /dev/input/eventX`

`xev`

Look for name in:

`xinput --list`

For example:

↳ TouchPad id=6 [slave  pointer  (2)] 
Then, type:

`xinput --list-props 6`

where 6 is the id returned in the first command.

Add any information returned to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I've been too busy to look at this in detail but your instructions have helped me to identify the main difference: the new version is using the synaptics driver, but the old version is using evdev.  I've awarded you the bounty since this is almost certainly my problem.  Hopefully if I can force X to use evdev on the new setup it will work like the old one again.

Comment: @jazzbassrob : Good luck.